# Test fails (correctly) on command line, but succeeds (incorrectly) in script

Tags: zsh, quoting, wildcards, test

For the sake of this question, assume that the glob `/a/b/c/*` produces no matches.

This means that the following test should fail (in other words, it should produce a non-zero `$?`):

```
[[ -n /a/b/c/*(#qN) ]]
```

This is in fact the case *if* I run the test directly on the (zsh) command line.  However, if I stick *the exact same test* in a script, it succeeds, which is not the intended behavior.

If I run the same script with the `-x` flag, the resulting trace shows the test as

```
[[ -n '/a/b/c/*(#qN)' ]]
```

I do not understand why the single quotes appear around test's argument; in the script's source code there are no quotes at all.

If zsh automatically inserts these single quotes, this would explain why the text succeeds.

Questions:

1. why is there a difference between the command-line and script versions of this expression?
2. what do I need to do so that the test (correctly) fails when it is in the script?

Comment: Is the `extended_glob` shell option set in both the interactive shell and the script?

Comment: @steeldriver: you beat me to it!  I just figured that out: `extendedglob` is set in my interactive environment, but not in the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS` section of the zsh manual:

> Filename generation is not performed on any form of argument to
> conditions.  However, it can be forced in any case where normal
> shell expansion is valid and when the option EXTENDED_GLOB is in
> effect  by  using    an  explicit  glob qualifier of the form (#q) at
> the end of the string.

In other words, in your script, where the `extendedglob` option is not set, `/a/b/c/*(#qN)` is treated as a literal string.

Answer (score 2):

A better idiom (IMO) to check whether a glob matches any file is with:

```
()(($#)) /a/b/c/*(NY1)
```

That does not require `extendedglob` and that special case of `[[ -n ...(#qN) ]]`. And is also more efficient thanks to that `Y1` which stops at the first match.

It works by passing the glob expansion to an anonymous function whose body is the `(($#))` arithmetic expression which returns true if the number of arguments to that anonymous function is non-zero.

You can extend it to things like:

```
if ()(( $# >= 3 )) /a/b/c*(NY3); then
  echo there were at least 3 matching files.
fi
```